# Using the resultset of a stored procedure in another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We are using SQL Server with ColdFusion. We have a stored procedure that takes 15 parameters, performs one query and returns a resultset (a temporary table with two columns). Based on this resultset, a pie chart is produced where the user can choose one segment of the pie and a report is produced only for that segment.

The chosen segment of the pie chart is a parameter I will use (in a second stored procedure probably) to filter through the resultset of the first stored procedure to get the results for the new report. Many users can use this combo with different parameters so I can't insert the resultset into a table.

Is there any way I can do this without executing the stored procedure twice?

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and what is your expected output.

Comment: Say the 1st SP receives l_startdate datetime = startdate,
l_enddate datetime = enddate,
l_locationidlist varchar(max) = locationidlist and returns a temp table, columns:contact, action. the new parameter for the 2nd SP is answer to a question. if the chosen answer is 'Other', I want to filter through the 1st resultset (the contact list) to get the contacts that chose the answer 'Other'. So I want the same output format as the 1st SP but filtered...

Comment: i would just add the answer as a parameter to the first procedure and leave it null when selecting the pie chart, and include the value when building the segment report. then just add your where statement like `AND (@Answer is null or chosen_answer = @Answer)`